# Why extensions method call is ambiguous?

Tags: c#, parameters, struct, extension-methods

I got these extensions:

```
internal static TResult With<TInput, TResult>
    (this TInput? o, Func<TInput, TResult> selector, TResult defaultResult = null)
    where TInput : struct
    where TResult : class
{
    selector.ThrowIfNull("selector");
    return o.HasValue ? selector(o.Value) : defaultResult;
}
internal static TResult? With<TInput, TResult>
    (this TInput? o, Func<TInput, TResult> selector, TResult? defaultResult = null)
    where TInput : struct
    where TResult : struct
{
    selector.ThrowIfNull("selector");
    return o.HasValue ? selector(o.Value) : defaultResult;
}
```

The first one is oriented at reference typed result and the second one on the Nullable of a struct.

So now why on the first line I got compilation error and on the second I do not?

1.

```
TimeSpan? time = ((int?)4).With(T => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(T))
// Error. The call is ambiguous.
```

2.

```
TimeSpan? time = ((int?)4).With(T => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(T), null)
// No errors. Normally calls the second extension.
```

Is not that obvius that TimeSpan (as a `TResult`) is a struct, which is specified at the very top of each extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Constaints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Comment: Well okay, not a part. But why then when I add the "null" at the end it all becomes clear to the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Th reason you get error on the first one because the return type is not a Nullable and you cast 4 to a nullable int

```
int? time = ((int?)4).With(T => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(T))
// Error. The call is ambiguous.
```

Comment: remove the answer i fixed the question

Comment: @AgentFire I already got -1 before you corrected your question

Answer (score 0):

Because `return type`  and `constraints` are not part of the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Generic constraints do not influence overload resultion. And when you omit second parameter, compiler has hard time determining what happens.